# How to share a TCP socket object between parent and (forked) child?

Tags: node.js, sockets, tcp, fork

I have an application in which my TCP server module (parent) listens for `'connection'` events and receives some data on the created socket to perform a handshake with the remote client. Once the handshake is performed, the server needs to send the socket object to a forked child, which will also send and receive data to the socket, do some stuff and finally send result to parent and be killed. For some reasons, I need to keep the socket object in the parent for further data processing not performed in the child, after the child has finished.

I've managed to send the socket to the child using the `subprocess.send()` method but, this way, the socket **handle** becomes `null` in the parent. I tried setting the `keepOpen` option to `true` and it *almost* worked, since I can send the socket and still work with it in the parent, but It seems not to work properly, because incoming data is not always received by the child `'data'` event listener.

I also tried to `removeListener` for the `'data'` event from the parent, prior to sending the socket to the child, but this made no difference, data is still being lost at some point on some occasions (on some others it is correctly received after an unexpected delay...). This code extract illustrates what I'm trying to do:

```
const net = require('net');
const server = net.createServer();
const cp = require('child_process');

server.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('data', (data) => {
    // Perform handhsake
    const child = cp.fork('child.js');
    child.on('message', (result) => {
      console.log('CHILD finished processing: ', result);
      child.kill('SIGHUP');
      // Do more stuff with socket
    });
    child.send('socket', socket);
    // (At this point, socket handle is null)
  });
});
server.listen(PORT)
```

I'm new to nodejs, I assume there might be errors in the code. Thanks.

Comment: Not by writing the descriptor to the socket. That's somewhat equivalent to trying to fax the fax machine. Depending on how the socket was created and modified at the OS level, it may already be inherited by the child process. NB You should not kill the child like that. Let it exit normally. I don't know why you think 'at this point, socket handle is null'. It isn't. And surely you don't really want to fork a child process for every message?

Comment: Where in the code am I supposed to be writing the descriptor to the socket? I don't get it... I think the socket handle is null because when I print the socket properties just after the "child.send('socket', socket)", it shows "_handle: null" (what it does not before) and also if I try to "socket.write" at that point, it throws "Error: This socket is closed". I understand that forking a child for every message is not the best approach, but I would like to understand what's happening there... Thanks for answering!

Comment: `child.send('socket', socket);` sends the socket descriptor to the child process, does it not?

Comment: Yes, it does. Well, in fact, it passes the "handle of the socket" to the child, as explained in the Node.js documentation (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_example_sending_a_socket_object). Reading that doc, it seems to be the right way to use the socket from the child process, I guess it would not be accesible from the child any other way...